# When do you answer a question in the comments vs. actually posting an answer?

Tags: discussion

A lot of times people answer questions in a comment instead of actually posting an answer; in fact, I just did it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463557/d3-how-to-make-this-variable-universal#30463557), which inspired me to ask this. This also just led to the somewhat common situation where the OP asks you to post it as an answer so that they can accept it.

I could have easily posted it as an answer, but I decided against it based on the precedent that I have seen across Stack Overflow. Is there a concrete rule that defines when you answer a question in the comment to the question itself vs. in an actual answer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to *answer the question*, provide a post that meets the site's standards for an acceptable post, are prepared for it to be evaluated by members of the community and wish for the content to be a permanent fixture, then you should post an answer.

If you have information that might be used to become an answer, but that isn't actually an answer (yet), then you can post it as a comment, if you want, to assist others in using that to write an *actual* answer.  Of course, in exchange for transforming the content that you've provided (in addition to whatever additional content they might add) they're the ones that are held responsible for that content's quality, meaning they'll be the one rewarded if it is quality content, and punished (if you consider losing a few Imaginary Internet Points punishment) if it's not quality content.

Answer (score 8):

Well, if you spot something wrong in the code that surely needs to be addressed but may, or may not, be the root cause of the OP's problem, you cannot honestly post it as an answer.  To prove it as the cause, you would have to implement a fix and test it.  Often, that would be a whole pile of work or actually not possible because you don't have the same environment as the OP.

I see something like that, I post a comment.  Let the OP try it out - they are the best ones to do it.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), and something I have been told on other sites, is that comments are not for answers.

> When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> Request clarification from the author;
>
> Leave constructive criticism
>   that guides the author in improving the post;
>
> Add relevant but minor
>   or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question,
>   or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).
>
> When shouldn't I comment?
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of
>   the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
>
> Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing
>   answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing
>   one);
>
> Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!");
>   instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;
>
> Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous
>   comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or up-vote
>   a better answer if appropriate);
>
> Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use
>   chat instead;
>
> Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta
>   instead.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I answer in a comment is when I'm pointing out the typo that also causes me to flag/vote for closure accordingly. Answering a question in a way that demands closure makes no sense, but silently closing as "oh there's a typo but we won't tell you where" doesn't seem right either.